# Is there an infinite binary sequence that satisfies every almost sure property of iid Bernoullis?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, cantor-set

Consider the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ where $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathcal F$ is the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $P$ is the law of an independent sequence of Bernoulli$(1/2)$ random variables. Let $$\mathcal A=\{A\in \mathcal F\colon P(A)=1\}$$
denote the collection of all almost sure events. Is the intersection of all sets in $\mathcal A$ non-empty?

---

I can't decide if it is empty or non-empty. On the one hand, it is easy to rule out many sequences from lying in the intersection: such a sequence cannot be eventually periodic, yet the set of ones in any such sequence must have density $1/2$ in $\mathbb N$. On the other hand, the (topological) support of the measure $P$ with respect to the product topology consists of *all* binary sequences (since every cylinder set containing a given sequence has positive measure), and one might expect that the support of $P$ is the closure of the intersection of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Isn't the complement of a single sequence an almost sure property?

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing this out. I guess the way to repair this question would be to restrict $\mathcal A$ to closed sets in a suitable topology, although it is not clear which choice of topology is most appropriate. Doing this in the product topology makes the intersection all of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, doing this in the discrete topology makes it empty, not sure if there is a natural topology in which the intersection is non-trivial. But I suppose this would belong in another question.

Comment: The natural topology to use would clearly be the product topology since that's the one which gives the natural setting for iid Bernoullis (because independent things correspond to product measures).

Comment: Yes, but that topology is not the one I am looking for because then the intersection is trivial. Maybe this should go in a separate post, but the question I am now asking is: does there exist a topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ (necessarily finer than the product topology and coarser than the discrete topology) such that, after extending the product measure to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by this topology, the intersection of all closed almost sure events is non-empty and not all of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$?